# is it possible to make my own toolbar for an internet browser using visual c++?

Tags: visual-c++, browser

we everyday use toolbars on browser such as google's, microsoft students',...
i was wondering how to create one using vc++ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below URLs for how to build toolbar for Internet explorer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735854%28VS.85%29.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/ietoolbartutorial.aspx